# Returning iterator consider static lifetime type

Tags: rust

```
fn expensive_sum(v: Vec<i32>) -> i32 {
    fun_name(v)
        .filter(|&x| x % 2 == 0)
        .map(|&x| x*x)
        .sum()
}

fn fun_name(v: Vec<i32>) -> std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> {
    v.iter()
}
```

Using https://depth-first.com/articles/2020/06/22/returning-rust-iterators/ as reference asking the compiler the return type of iterator obtained `std::slice::Iter<'_, i32>` but when compiling:

```
error[E0106]: missing lifetime specifier
  --> src/main.rs:25:46
   |
25 | fn fun_name(v: Vec<i32>) -> std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> {
   |                                              ^^ expected named lifetime parameter
   |
   = help: this function's return type contains a borrowed value, but there is no value for it to be borrowed from
help: consider using the `'static` lifetime
   |
25 | fn fun_name(v: Vec<i32>) -> std::slice::Iter<'static, i32> {
   |
```

What does that mean? And why should I consider using the `static` lifetime?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```rust
fn fun_name(v: Vec<i32>) -> std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> {
    v.iter()
}
```

The problem with this function is the same as with this one

```rust
fn foo(x: i32) -> &'what_lifetime_goes_here i32 {
    &x
}
```

`fun_name` takes an ownership of `v` and then you try to return something that borrows from function body. This is impossible. You tried *cheat* the compiler by using an anonymous lifetime `'_` but rust still has to figure out what this lifetime really is. Your function isn't generic over any lifetime, so rustc figures out that the only lifetime that would make sense here is `'static`. However this will not solve your real problem, because you cannot borrow `v` for `'static`, as it will be dropped at the end of the function.

You have two options here. You can either take ownership of `v`, as `fun_name` already does, but then you will have to return iterator that owns vec's data [std::vec::IntoIter](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) and will yield `i32`.

```rust
fn fun_name(v: Vec<i32>) -> std::vec::IntoIter<i32> {
    v.into_iter()
}
```

Or on the other hand you could make `fun_name` borrow `v`, and then you could return an iterator of inner slice, which will have a lifetime of the lifetime of the `v` borrow.

```rust
fn fun_name(v: &Vec<i32>) -> std::slice::Iter<'_, i32> {
    v.iter()
}
```

Comment: In the last case it would be better to take `&[i32]` since that type is more general and [`&Vec<T>` is discouraged](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40006219/why-is-it-discouraged-to-accept-a-reference-string-vec-or-box-as-a-function)

Comment: @cafce25 This is true. I intentionally left it `&Vec` to not stir confusion. But later it probably should be changed to `&[T]`.

Comment: @cafce25 could you explain better what you mean?

Comment: @pedro_bb7 They provided a link, follow it.